# error: expected primary-expression before '<' token

Tags: c++, linux

I compiled the below code with gcc4.4.1 on linux:-

```
#include "glob.h"
#include "netlist.h"
#include "netlist_params.h"
#include "netlist_abbrev.h"
#include "lvs_util.h"
#include "lvs_report.h"
#include "lvs_data.h"
#include "compare_opts.h"
#include "flatten.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "hash.h"

static THREAD_PRIVATE NlStringVec*  ext_str_tab_v;
static THREAD_PRIVATE const char*   ext_str_tab_s1;
static THREAD_PRIVATE const char*   ext_str_tab_s2;


int  Netlist::ExtStrHash::operator () (NlString i) const {
  if (i.is_valid())
    ext_str_tab_s1 = (*ext_str_tab_v)[i];
  return Hash<const char*>::operator()(ext_str_tab_s1);
}
```

Error:-

```
netlist_back_1.C: In member function 'int Netlist::ExtStrHash::operator()(NlString) const':
netlist_back_1.C:24: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
netlist_back_1.C:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
netlist_back_1.C:24: error: expected ';' before 'const'
netlist_back_1.C:24: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
netlist_back_1.C:24: error: expected initializer before '>' token
```

Definition of hash in file hash.h:-

```
    namespace Hash {

      //  template <class Key> struct Hash { };

    #define DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(type) \
    template <> \
    struct Hash<type> { \
      unsigned int operator() (type x) const { return x; } \
    }

      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(signed char);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(unsigned char);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(signed short);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(unsigned short);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(signed int);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(unsigned int);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(signed long);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(unsigned long);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(signed long long);
      DECL_SIMPLE_HASH(unsigned long long);

    #undef DECL_SIMPLE_HASH

      template <>  
      class Hash<const char*> {
        static const int M = 61; // 5;

      public:

        unsigned int  operator() (const char* s) const {
          // case insensitive, so sensitivity can be turned on/off without
          // effecting hash #.
          unsigned h = 0;
          char c;
          while (c = *s++) {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
          c = c - 'A' + 'a';
        h = M*h + c;
          }
          return h;
        }
      };

      template <> struct Hash<char*> : public Hash<const char*> {};
}
```

EDIT:: I needed to include the namespace. Working on other's code lead to foolish mistakes.
Thanks for vote down and help. :)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Write `Hash<const char*>(ext_str_tab_s1)` wouldn't be easier?

Comment: Are you including something that defines what Hash is?

Comment: Is the template class `Hash` not included and/or defined in a namespace? If so that is likely your issue.

Comment: Looks like the compiler doesn't recognize `Hash<>` as a type... where is it declared (and in what namespace)?

Comment: I agree that there must be probably the same problem you guys are suggesting, but it is difficult to find out

Comment: Why is there a has namespace, Hash struct and Hash class? And where does the Hash namespace end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see:

- You're not including `"hash.h"`
- You've commented out the declaration of the `Hash` template, leaving only the explicit specialisations. You still need to declare the template, even if you don't define the generic version.
- The `Hash` template is inside a namespace `Hash`, but you neither use that namespace nor fully qualify the template name. (By the way, it's not a very good idea to use the same name for a namespace and a class; it can lead to ambiguities).
- You're trying to call a non-static `operator()` as if it's static; you want something more like `return Hash<const char*>()(ext_str_tab_s1);`.

So it's no surprise that `Hash` is not recognised as a template name (although it has to be said that the error message is not very helpful).

Comment: @crazy_prog, this is a good answer. And, you need to step back a little. Where did this code come from? There are quite a lot of issues with it. Did you write it yourself? Did any version of it ever work?

Answer (score 2):

There are few possible options :

- you didn't include the header where the `Hash` template is defined
- the template `Hash` is in different namespace

Answer (score 1):

`Hash` is a namespace.  Namespaces can't have template parameters.

Don't give types and namespaces the same name.